# Unable to reference Class member (Array) in $scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `factory('CriteriaSelector')` --> (a class CriteriaSelector) with member variable `selectedValues = []` (an array). 
I am trying to reference this in scope as follows :

```
// in controller
$scope.criteriaSelector = new CriteriaSelector();
$scope.selectedValues = $scope.criteriaSelector.selectedValues;
//The above code according to me should point to the same array.
```

I want a behavior, where if `$scope.criteriaSelector.selectedValues` gets updated then it should reflect in `$scope.selectedValues` and vice versa.

But the problem is I don't see this change reflecting in `$scope.selectedValues`

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

By doing it like this, the value will be initialize (on controller init) and won't be able to change. If you want an updated value, you have to use method.

On your factory it will be something like this :

```
yourFactory.getSelectedValues = function(){
   return selectedValues;
}

yourFactory.setSelectedValues = function(values){
   selectedValues = values;
}
```

And the with the getter, for example, you can make the data-binding :

```
$scope.getSelectedValues = $scope.criteriaSelector.getSelectedValues
```

Here you do'nt put the `( )`. Like this, you will match to the function and not the value. You will be able to get the data on your DOM like this after that :

```
 {{getSelectedValues() }}
```

And here, your data will be refresh at any change.